# Office365 forms iframe shows scrollbar

Tags: forms, iframe, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to embed Office365 form on SharePoint Online site via an iframe but the page shows scrollbar. I tried `scrolling="no"` on **iframe** and `overflow:hidden` in **style** but that does not help.

Did anyone come across this issue before and is there any suggested fix?

Comment: Are you looking for help remove vertical scrollbar for the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
   iframe{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

or

```
 "width:100%;height:100%"
```

may be the issue. Try make size of the iframe larger than the frame window.

If this is not working, try the following line.

```
 #s4-workspace {

   overflow-y: hidden !important;

   overflow-x: hidden !important;

}
```